# Javascript function keeps being called although its class is null

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'd be happy if you could explain to me why shout() keeps getting called, although it's supposedly "gone".

```
var myclass = new Class({
myid: "greatidea",
initialize: function(element) {
    var shout = function() { alert(this.myid); };
    shout.periodical(5000, this); // test debug
}
```

`});

    x = new myclass ();

alert(x);

x=null;

alert(x);`

also see here http://mootools.net/shell/jhCBz/

Basically, I get the idea: the function gets its own registration, and is now independent of the object who called it. But I'd be happy to get a real explanation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` held a reference to `myclass`. `myclass` is executing `shout`. When you set `x` to `null`, you are just getting rid of your reference to `myclass`, not the `myclass` object itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jball. Is there another way to stop the function calls (except for clearing the periodical timer)?

Comment: yeah it fails even if the periodical reference is a property of the class: http://mootools.net/shell/ZBrm7/1/ 

it continues even if you remove the class itself. very annoying - but you may have to code a .destroy() method which does $clear(this.timer);

Comment: I built a different periodical/delay interface which allows you to track and remove any deferred functions at your whim - check http://mootools.net/shell/judGJ/ - it may give you some ideas and you can build that into your class. Even though it's fairly robust/fast and serves my garbage collection purposes, i would not recommend using it in animations that are FPS dependent due to overhead of moving data.

Answer (score 6):

Functions are *always* independent. As long as there's a reference to a function, it continues to exist. And in this case, so does your object, since you've passed a reference to it (via `this`) to the `periodical()` function, which holds onto it for context.